# Batch "If was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to write a simple batch file to run the Tracert command, and the user can input if he wants a list of local devices to trace, in which case userResponse equals y, or if he doesn't, in which case it equals n. When I launch the application, the prompt to enter y or n appears and no matter what I write, the error message "if was unexpected at this time appears" and the screen quickly closes. After browsing Stack Overflow for a while, I tried the following fixes :

- Putting the text of the user inputs between quotes.
- Adding `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

But none of those solutions worked.

Here's the code.

```
@echo off
color A
title Trace Route
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p userResponse="Would you like a list of local devices to trace (y/n)? "

if %userResponse%==y (

net view

set /p IPAddress="Enter the IP address that you would like to trace: " 
echo.
set /p addressType="Enter the IP Address type (4 or 6): "

tracert -%addressType% %IPAddress%

PAUSE

) if %userResponse%==n (

set /p IPAddress="Enter the IP address that you would like to trace: " 
echo.
set /p addressType="Enter the IP Address type (4 or 6): "

tracert -%addressType% %IPAddress%

PAUSE
)
```

I'm a beginner to Stack Exchange, so forgive me if any information is missing. I'll quickly add it on request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `if` only at the start of a line, so instead of

```
) if %userResponse%==n (
```

use

```
)
if %userResponse%==n (
```

batch is kind of strict with brackets. Note that you also can't use

```
if %userResponse%==n
(
```

The opening bracket needs to be on the same line as the if statement

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly!! Thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: quick question, does the tracing work for you? if not (which I think), try using ! instead of % inside your if statements.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it. Thanks again!

Comment: Just for future reference, when using SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, you should always make sure the variables that get expanded at runtime use ! markers, read more about this here: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it